# is normal bundle of a manifold trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

If you embed a manifold $M$ in Euclidean space, is the normal bundle always trivial? Or give an example with non-trivial normal bundle.

Answer (score 5):

If $M$ is non-orientable, its normal bundle must also be non-orientable (or you could use it to find an orientation on $M$ itself).

Comment: But I think tubular neighborhood of open Mobius strip in R^3 is open solid torus.

Comment: @Neel: The underlying space is an open solid torus, but it's non-orientable (and therefore nontrivial) as a bundle over the Mobius strip.