# Normal bundle of a non-orientable manifold

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, tangent-bundle, non-orientable-surfaces

What I know:

- A tangent bundle $TM$ of a manifold $M$ is orientable if and only if the manifold $M$ is orientable.
- If the first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1(E) \neq 0$, the vector bundle $E$ is non-orientable.
- The first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1 \in H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$, where $M$ is the base space.

I read an Answer: If a manifold $M$ embedded in Euclidean space is non-orientable, its normal bundle must also be non-orientable. (from here [is normal bundle of a manifold trivial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554797/is-normal-bundle-of-a-manifold-trivial))

My question: How to prove the answer above using $w_1(NM)\neq 0$?

Comment: I just wanted to mention a small point of language regarding $TM$.  When you write $TM$ is orientable if and only if $M$ is orientable, this is true in one sense and false in another.  It's true that $TM$, as a bundle over $M$ is non-orientable as a bundle if $M$ is non-orientable as a manifold.  However, as a manifold $TM$ is always orientable, regardless of orientability of $M$.  The point is that some people (like me) get lazy in specifying bundle-orientable vs manifold-orientable, so one must be careful about results,e.g.,  like "If a vector bundle is orientable, it has an Euler class".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is embedded into the standard inner product space $\Bbb{R}^n$.
Since $TM \oplus NM \cong M \times \Bbb{R}^n$, by the Whitney sum formula, $w(TM) \cdot w(NM)=w(TM \oplus NM)=w(M \times \Bbb{R}^n)=1 \in H^0(M;\Bbb{Z}_2)$ where $w$ denotes the total Stiefel-Whitney class.
Specifically, $w_1(TM) + w_1(NM)=w_1(M \times \Bbb{R}^n)=0 \in H^1(M;\Bbb{Z}_2)$, which means $w_1(NM) = w_1(TM) \ne 0$.

Comment: Hi Zerox, thanks for the answer. If $M$ is immersed into $\mathbb{R}^n$, do we still have $TM \oplus NM  \cong M \times \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @Phi Depends on how you define $NM$.

Comment: For example, if a m-dimensional manifold $M$ is immersed into $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}$, then the NM defined in $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ has fiber with 1-dimension $\mathbb{R}$. Does the NM with $\mathbb{R}$ fiber follows  $TM \oplus NM \cong M \times \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$?

Comment: @Phi What I really want to ask is: How do you define the fibers at singular points of the image such as self-intersections?

Comment: @ Zerox  Here I got an answer, if you are interested in. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440727/is-tm-oplus-nm-cong-m-times-mathbbrn-valid-if-the-manifold-m-is-immers

Comment: This is what I mean "how to define the 'normal bundle'."